# configure static ip address To My website application

Tags: java, html, web-services, networking, network-programming

- i am new in net working, i know only JAVA & HTML & DATABASE ORACLE
- i have small scale merchant business clients.
- i buying website with PHP,FTP Accounts,MySQL Databases,SMTP Server
- i developed one App using Java,html,oracle-DB , tomcat server( ex: login page with username & password)
- my internet service provided one static ip( XX.XXX.XXX.XXX when i run this ip from any location like as XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/Login.html then it will be open Login page).
- now how can i run this ip from my website like (http://MyAppSite.com:8080 or http://MyAppSite.com )
- is it possible using this,(i want finish low cost because of all clients are very small scale merchants)
- advance thanks, give any solutions very helpfully to me.

Comment: did you run local machine server 24*7?

Comment: Yes.it will run continuous..

Answer (score 0):

You need to point a domain name to your local IP address. I personally use Namecheap, and LOVE them! So much better than the bloated GoDaddy, that tries to sell a dozen upsells to you.

How to point your domain to your IP Address: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1162/10/how-can-i-point-my-domain-name-to-my-home-servers-ip

You will need to setup a Virtual Host on your computer/server to handle the incoming traffic from that domain name, so your computer knows where to redirect it.

Tutorial, with pics, to setup a VHost on WAMP: https://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

The links to good resources are far better than me writing a lengthy post, explaining things that are all over the internet. Once you know what you need to do (point your domain to your IP, setup virtual host on WAMP, MAMP, ect), a few searches will go a long way.

I understand, sometimes it's hard to find your solution, when you have no idea what your needing to search for. There are thousands of tutorials all over the internet, and probably video tutorials on YouTube.

I hope my guidance gets you in the right direction.